# JPA and Predefined Instances of Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an application using JPA (Hibernate implementation), in which I have several entities defined with annotations, e.g.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="my_table")
public class MyEntity {
  //various fields
}
```

I also have an SQL script to insert records into the database as soon as the schema is created - these pre-inserted records are actually constant, so not expected to change during execution.

Is it possible to get these pre-inserted records as static instances of the entities, e.g.:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="my_table")
public class MyEntity {

  public static MyEntity constantEntity...
  //various fields
}
```

Comment: IMO it's not worth the effort. You can get them from the database and detach them, but Hibernate will complain that these objects are not part of the active session. If you want to re-attach them to the session, the database is going to be hit anyways, to verify that nothing changed, and you will need to clone them by hand, as an entity can't be in two sessions at once...

Comment: It's clearly "possible" since the JPA API allows you to get an object and detach it. Why you would want to do that is up to you. And not all JPA implementations need to go to the datastore to know if a detached object has been changed (since bytecode enhancement used by the likes of DataNucleus JPA provides that functionality, hence avoiding the need to go to the datastore)